# Failed to build gem native extension while installing therubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, therubyracer

I suppose it may help to know that I am using uru with two versions of Ruby because of nogokiri gem not supporting ruby 2.2. Also I don't know why does it say something about python (I have 3.4.3 python installed)

```
C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
which: no python in (.;C:\RoR\DevKit\bin;C:\RoR\DevKit\mingw\bin;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;_U_;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\watcom-1.3\binnt;C:\watcom-1.3\binw;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\; C:\Ruby22-x64\bin; C:\SQLite;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\SQLite)
System cannot find the path specified.
which: no python in (.;C:\RoR\DevKit\bin;C:\RoR\DevKit\mingw\bin;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;_U_;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\watcom-1.3\binnt;C:\watcom-1.3\binw;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\; C:\Ruby22-x64\bin; C:\SQLite;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\SQLite)
C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/builder.rb:81:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/builder.rb:55:in `block in build_libv8!'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `chdir'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `build_libv8!'
    from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

From error message:

> libv8 requires python 2

From your post:

> I have 3.4.3 python installed

Python 2 != python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell by your path, but have you tried using [the Devkit for RubyGems](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/)? I remember it was pretty painless from when I was working with Ruby raw on my Windows box.

Comment: PATH suggests that he is already using the DevKit or something with the same name: `which: no python in (.;C:\RoR\DevKit\bin...`